# Is this a valid IPtables command?

Tags: debian, firewall, iptables

I have to add redirect rules for several thousand IP ranges but I am complete newbie when it comes to IP tables and want to make sure I got this right..

```
iptables
-t nat
-A PREROUTING
-p tcp
-m iprange --src-range 111.222.333.64-111.222.333.140
--dport 25 -j REDIRECT --to 1025
```

If I understand correctly, that will forward any IP between `111.222.333.64` and `111.222.333.140` that was destined for port `25` to redirect instead to port `1025`, is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about what you said in regard to this rule, but there is one important thing that should be said.

Using `REDIRECT`, will redirect this type of traffic to the firewall machine itself not to the original destination IP address. If you want to change only the destination port (not the IP as well), you need to use `DNAT` target instead.